# How can I distinguish a service form a process in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

Is there a way to determine if an entry listed in Activity Monitor is a service (daemon) or a process (application)?

Examples:

- Firefox (application)
- com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper (daemon?)

Is there a good definition of what these terms (that I'm using loosely) mean in OS X?

Comment: What do you want to do, once you know the difference? Services are often essential to the parent application process.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the architecture.

Comment: Please can you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for *Does the application need to be built in specific way (e.g. no UI, implement certain interfaces) so it can be used as a service?`* Ask Different works best when each question is asked separately. Feel free to refer to other questions in your new question.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345640/do-applications-in-os-x-need-to-be-built-in-specific-way-to-be-used-as-a-service

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## All Processes, Hierarchically

Activity Monitor can show the process hierarchy:

**Activity Monitor.app > View (menu) > All Processes, Hierarchically**

The grouping shows those processes launched by another process. Typically child-process will be services of the parent. On macOS many of these child processes will be XPC instances.

### Services are Processes

On macOS, daemons are processes and services are processes. In your example, `com.apple.audio.SandboxHelper`, this is an [XPC service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html).

Comment: Why do all processes (except `kernel_task`) run as children of `launchd`?

Comment: This would make a great [new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). The root process in macOS is `launchd` and Apple have decided to put almost every process launch through it. I suspect it has many benefits but those can be discussed in a new question.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345639/why-do-all-processes-except-kernel-task-run-as-children-of-launchd

Answer (score 6):

Technically speaking, anything that gets loaded and executed is a process; so a service is a process.

A service is a nuanced definition of something that gets loaded to provide a service like DHCP or DNS.

A alternative way to sum this up is *all services are processes, but not all processes are services*.  An example would be Firefox, it's a process, but not a service - it's an application.