# Do executables in OS X need to be built in specific way to be used as a service?

Tags: macos

Does an OS X executables need to be built in specific way (e.g. no UI, implement certain interfaces) so it can be used as a service?  Does this vary by its language (e.g. Objective C, Java) or its implementation (compiled versus script)?

Answer (score 2):

An executable on macOS can be run as a service or application *almost* regardless of how it is created.

The question to ask is, **does the process require access to the WindowServer?** The WindowServer is needed to provide a graphical interface.

## Graphical User Interface and User Sessions

A process requiring a graphical user interface can be used as a background process or service. Do this by launching the process with `launchd` from the `/Library/LaunchAgents` folder.

To present a graphical user interface, the process must be launched within a user session. In `launchd` terms this means within an `Aqua` environment.

An example of this would be Power Manager's [`pmuser`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/developer/pme.agent.pmuser.html) process. This process manages tasks specific to the user and handles tasks that the computer wide [`pmd`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/developer/pm.tool.pmd.html) process can not directly perform.

## Computer Wide Processes

A process that does not require a user interface can be launched as a background service with `launchd` from the `/Library/LaunchDaemons` folder.

A non-graphical process can exist outside of any user session and thus run even when no-one is logged in.

A computer wide process can not access much of macOS's unique functionality. See Apple's TechNote 2083 and the [Living Dangerously](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION23) section.

Comment: So an application needs to be launched by `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, correct?  The fact that most process are children (or some ancestor) of `launchd` seems to suggest this.

Comment: Applications launched by the user will have `launchd` as the parent. Only daemons, services, and background tasks *need* to be [launched directly from the launchd folders](http://www.launchd.info). What are you trying to set up?